# Can't save profiles (any type) getting an error, this is CIVI Crm 5.x and drupal 7 on localhost

Tags: error

Whenever I try to edit or save a profile, I get this error:

```
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: no such field
```

Error in D7 log messages is:

```
Type    page not found
Date    Sunday, September 30, 2018 - 11:39
User    1
Location    http://localhost/crm4/undefinedjs/jquery/jquery.crmAjaxTable.js
Referrer    http://localhost/crm4/civicrm
Message undefinedjs/jquery/jquery.crmAjaxTable.js
Severity    warning
Hostname    ::1
Operations
```

Comment: Can you check CiviCRM logs for more detail about 'DB Error: no such field'. Did you upgrade civicrm recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, disabled the jQuery update module.

I could play around with Jquery versions as I am using Boostrap with different themes so I'll leave it off for now.

But no doubt, playing with Jquery versions on admin theme would solve this also ;)